# Highchart logarithmic X axis fail without zero values nor threshold under zero nor minimum

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with logarithmic X-axis.
Have a threshold above 0, minimum of x is 1 and all X values are above 0. And still giving me the same error [Can't plot zero or subzero values on a logarithmic axis](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/10)

Here is a fiddle with the problem (and the code)
http://jsfiddle.net/y31gwofL/3/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "logarithmic",
            min: 1
        },
                yAxis: {
            type: "linear"
        },
        series: [
        {
            type: "line",
            data: [
                {
                    "name": 1,
                    "y": 9.991242714224013
                },
                {
                    "name": 2,
                    "y": 9.991242714224013
                },
                {
                    "name": 3,
                    "y": 9.991242714224011
                },
                {
                    "name": 4,
                    "y": 9.991242714224015
                },
                {
                    "name": 5,
                    "y": 9.991242714224015
                },
                {
                    "name": 6,
                    "y": 9.991242714224008
                },
                {
                    "name": 7,
                    "y": 9.991242714224015
                },
                {
                    "name": 8,
                    "y": 9.991242714224015
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are telling it to take the log of "1" or "2" or "3", etc. You are defining your xAxis as a series of categories instead of integers. Make your series data like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "logarithmic",
            min: 1
        },
                yAxis: {
            type: "linear"
        },
        series: [
        {
            type: "line",
            data: [
                {
                    "x": 1,
                    "y": 9.991242714224013
                },
                {
                    "x": 2,
                    "y": 9.991242714224013
                },
                {
                    "x": 3,
                    "y": 9.991242714224011
                },
                {
                    "x": 4,
                    "y": 9.991242714224015
                },
                {
                    "x": 5,
                    "y": 9.991242714224015
                },
                {
                    "x": 6,
                    "y": 9.991242714224008
                },
                {
                    "x": 7,
                    "y": 9.991242714224015
                },
                {
                    "x": 8,
                    "y": 9.991242714224015
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    });
});
```

Note I have replaced `"name"` with `"x"`.